# Is there any way I could know if a user submitted a review on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an android application.

One feature we are trying to implement is free use time for those who has submitted a review. From the first week since register, users get free access to some of our items. However, after that first week, they need to write a review to get the free items.

We looked at various solutions for this. For example, write a submit button pressed listener. However, users who has submitted a review without pressing the submit button won't get the free items.

We looked at [unofficial Google Market API](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/). However, too glitchy.

Are there anyway if a user has submitted a review for my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason there is no API: it is against the [Google Play Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> Developers must not attempt to change the placement of any Product in the Store, or manipulate any product ratings or reviews, by unauthorized means such as fraudulent installs, paid or fake reviews or ratings, or by **offering incentives to rate products**.

Comment: Oh... One of my colleague said offering incentives to give "high" votes or "positive" comments were illegal, not incentives to just vote or comment...
My bad.

Comment: But I see a lot of games offering free items to rate them... I guess Google can't check every application...

Comment: @JeeSeokYoon - I think Google goes much more of a user report system then necessarily manually checking every app. Please report those apps to raise it to Google's attention.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for the Google Play store.  It is not possible to know if a user has left a review (or which rating they left).

You can keep track if they press a button in your app to link to the store, but not determine what they did after they linked there.

Bottom line, there is NO way to determine a user rating on an app.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think we can get the user review with [unofficial Google Market API](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)(It gives you the author ID, but I don't know what that is...). I agree that there is "NO way" to determine a user rating.